# How to do paging with grouping mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query

is there a way to create paging with grouping in Mongo?
trying to do it in a generic way to make a common pager, so ideally, it should be possible to define an expression or rule for grouping outside of this pager, but even without this I cannot find a way to group and do the paging.

Ideally, I want this:

```
        List<T> data = await collection.Aggregate()
            .Match(filterDefinition)
            .Sort(sortDefinition)
            .Group(groupDefinition) // group definition does not exist in mongo driver:)
            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
            .Limit(pageSize)
            .ToListAsync();
```

and currently, all that I have achieved is this:

```
        T[] data = await collection.Aggregate()
            .Match(filterDefinition)
            .Sort(sortDefinition)
            .Group(new JsonProjectionDefinition<T>(@"{'_id': '$Name', 'docs' : { '$push': '$$ROOT' }}")) // to push entire documents from grouping operation
            .Project<IGrouping<TKey, T>[]>>(new JsonProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument>(@"{'grouped_paged': '$docs'}"))
            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
            .Limit(pageSize)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

But projection doesn't work in any combination, with a slice or without a slice(cannot deserialize because there are non-white space characters). Is there a way to return this grouping? or I hope there is one solution from the box that I'm missing

Maybe someone has already faced such an issue?

Comment: it seems you want to requery for each page.  Each query has a skip, so it can skip to the next section.  You also have a match and a sort clause.  This strategy can cause page issues if new records (that match your $match stage) or if deletes occur in between pagination events.  A better approach is to keep the cursor open and iterate it for each page as needed.  But this is harder to program.